# What determines the lifetime of a Teiid session?

Tags: teiid

When accessing Teiid via jdbc, when is the lifetime of a Teiid session?  It it the same as the lifetime of a connection?

I would like to create a temporary table with one connection and read it with a different one.  Is this possible?  If so, when would it be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, life of connection = life of session. A session scoped temporary table is not for sharing across the connections. See [1] for temporary table support.

[1] http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/12.3.x/content/reference/Temp_Tables.html